# How to know if pairing was successful from logcat?

Tags: android, android-logcat

I'm reading a logcat now, trying to understand why 2 devices couldn't connect via bluetooth. Is there a way to know if the 2 devices were paired successfully only by reading the logcat? I don't have the devices with me, just trying to understand the situation by reading to logs.

maybe i should look for the `BluetoothBondState`. is there a definition for these states somewhere?

Comment: Devices are emulators or real devices?

Comment: Real. A mobile phone and a headset.

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661932/problem-with-bluetooth-on-android-2-1-samsung-spica-i5700-where-pairing-works

Comment: The solution there was to upgrade the firmware. that's not any updated firmware in my case. maybe bond state 10->11 saying that devices paired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending from your comment, and from the [documentations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#BOND_BONDED):

During bonding the constant `public static final int BOND_BONDING` has the value `11 (0x0000000b)`.

And once, the bond is successful, the constant `public static final int BOND_BONDED` has the value `12 (0x0000000c)`.